# how to change <Html "lang"/> with next-i18next when language changed in nextjs?

Tags: next.js, i18next, next-i18next

I'm using next-i18next for multi language website and for all components works well but I dont know how to change the language of html tag in _document.js file?

Comment: Where can I find the sample _document.js file? I cannot find it in next-18next repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution.

```
class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
     const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
     const language = ctx.req.language
     return { ...initialProps, language }
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <Html lang={this.props.language}>
         <Head />
         <body>
           <Main />
           <NextScript />
         </body>
       </Html>
    ) 
  } 
}
```

Comment: thank you it needs a refresh after that every thing is ok